# Можно ли будет распространять macOs приложения построенные с помощью Catalyst минуя AppStore?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Сейчас я могу создать приложение для macOs старым способом, подписать его своим девелоперским сертификатом и распространять его через свой сайт миную Mac AppStore.

Можно ли будет так делать с приложениями построенными на Catalyst?

Кстати в каком формате компилируется приложение .app или .ipa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно, собирается также, как обычный бинарник для macOS

на выходе .pkg/.app